# how can i use require(""); in javascript

Tags: javascript, firefox, plugins, requirejs, mozilla

i want to use a plugin in Firefox that it is in [this](https://github.com/inbasic/media-converter/blob/master/connect.md). in this plugin tutorial use `require` function, and it is: `require("sdk/preferences/service");`

but i get error that `require is not defined`. so i search and download [requireJS](http://requirejs.org/). but when attach this i get error `module name sdk/preference/service has not been loaded yet from context. use require([])`.

so i use `require(["sdk/preferences/service"],function(pref){});` but in function i can't use pref and get error `script error sdk/preferences/service`

so how can i use require function?

or a HTML example that use require function and it works correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you found was for use *in* a Firefox extension. You’re not writing a Firefox extension, you’re using a web page, so you can’t use that code. There’s no drop-in replacement; you’ll have to find something else.